# Invalid operand error in overloaded operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operand

So I'm really confused about why I'm getting this invalid operand error. I have two classes, classA and ClassB. ClassB contains three ClassA pointers. The ClassA operator+= has been overloaded as follows:

```
ClassA& ClassA::operator+=(const ClassA& rhs)
{
    (*this).dataMem += rhs.dataMem;
    return *this;
}
```

And that works and everything. My problem comes in when I'm overloading the operator+= and operator+ in ClassB. The operator should just perform the + operation on the ClassA objects within it.

```
ClassB& ClassB::operator+=(const ClassB& rhs)
{
    (*this).mClassA + rhs.mClassA;
    return *this;
}
```

I am confused because I have overloaded other operators in ClassB using the exact same format and calls, but I am only receiving the invalid operand error while overloading the + and += operator.

This is the error that I'm receiving:
    ClassB.cpp:93: error: invalid operands of types ClassA* and ClassA* const to binary operator+.

Any sort of help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is mClassA in Class B is defined constant? need to look at its declaration

Comment: No, it is not defined as a constant. It doesn't seem like it needs to be a constant, does it? It's a pointer to a ClassA object.

Comment: so you are adding two pointers? right?

Comment: Those aren't objects, they're pointers, and you can't add pointers.

Comment: I am! And that fixed it for me!

*((*this).mClassA) += *(rhs.mClassA) seems to be working, or, compiling.

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void ClassB::operator+=(const ClassB& rhs)
{
    (*this).mClassA + rhs.mClassA;
}
```

This function accepts an argument of type ClassB, so operator + of ClassA will not be called when you call this modify it to

```
void ClassB::operator+=(const ClassA& rhs)
{
    (*this).mClassA + rhs.mClassA;
}
```

and it will work

Comment: a bit late, because it was testing it on my machine :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be to perform something like 
    mClassB += mClassA

Comment: It seems like just dereferencing both (*this).mClassA and rhs.mClassA worked